# Does anyone know the reason why the variables have to be defined at the top of function

Tags: c

I have a question, does anyone know why the variables have to be defined <s>initialized</s> at the beginning of a function?  Why can't you initialize or define variables in the middle of a function in C as in C++?

Comment: Even with pre-C99 compilers, a local variable doesn't have to be initialized until you are ready to initialize it.

Comment: If your C compiler does not support variables in the middle of a function, it does not support C99 and it is time to upgrade to one which does.

Comment: Even in pre-standard C, you could always define variables at the start of any statement block (for example, after the `{` in `if (expr) { ... }`) inside a function.  You could not introduce variables after the first non-declaration or non-definition until C99 granted you the same permission that C++ had long given (and you had a C99 compiler).

Comment: _Historical note_: The structure of blocks and declarations in C was inherited from Algol 60, which apparently invented the declarations-at-the-start-of-a-block principle. (Algol 58 appears to have allowed declarations anywhere at the _top level_ of a procedure body, but _nowhere_ in inner blocks). Writing parsers was still something of a black art around 1960, so having declarations anywhere could well have been a real problem then. When C was invented in the early 1970s, it wouldn't have burdened a compiler significantly. but by then there were already traditions to follow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a tradition which comes from early C compilers, when compiler needs all local variable definitions before the actual code of function starts (to generate right stack pointer calculation). This was the only way of declaring local variables in early C language, both pre-standard (K&R) and first C standard, C90, published at 1989-1990 ( ANSI X3.159-1989,  ISO/IEC 9899:1990 ).

C99 - the 1999 year ISO standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) of C allows declaraions in the middle of function.

C++ allows this because it is newer language than C. C++ standards are ISO/IEC 14882:1998 and ISO/IEC 14882:2003, so they are from 1998 and 2003 years.

You can initialize variable (give it a value: `a=4;`) at the definition point or any time later.

Answer (score 7):

That is a left-over from early C. C99 allows variables to be defined anywhere in the function, including in loop structures.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { int j; }
```

The throwback is from when compilers needed to know the size of the stack for the function before they instantiated the function's code. As compilers became better the requirement just became annoying.

Comment: But even early C allowed declarations in inner blocks, and also allowed `goto` statements to jump into such blocks from outside. So an emit-code-while-parsing compiler would still need to backpatch the local-variable size in the function prologue after having translated each function body. More than compiler limitations in early C, I think the explanation must be that everybody were used to declarations being separate, such that it didn't even occur to the designers that allowing them to intermix with code would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in C so long as you use a C99 compiler. The restriction was lifted in C99.

Presumably the restriction was originally there because compilers were less capable, or perhaps simply because nobody thought of allowing such a convenience for the programmer.

When answering a question like this it is sometimes worth turning it around. Why would the original designers of C have done it the other way? They didn't have C++ to guide them!

Comment: I downvoted this because originally it said "just go and use a C99 compiler" which I believed didn't help at all, since it appeared to be a question about "why," that is, what design decision/limitation was behind making it that way. You've improved it a lot now, so if you modify your answer slightly so it will let me remove my downvote and @ me, I'll do so.

Comment: @Seth I found the question hard to understand in its original form due to the language barrier.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ and C99, you *can* define variables in the middle of a function. What you cannot do is *refer* to a variable that has not yet been defined.

From the point of view of object-oriented programming, it wouldn't make much sense otherwise: By defining a variable you bring an object to life (by calling its constructor). Before that, there *is* no object, so there's nothing to interact with until you pass the point of object construction.

Comment: Consider, however, ActionScript, a class-based language in which local variables are always visible and alive in the _entire_ function they belong to, even if their declaration is lexically deep inside an inner loop. (I wouldn't go as far as saying this _makes sense_, so you're right after all).

Comment: Henning: Well, you could of course design a language without such restrictions -- the compiler or runtime would just have to look ahead and figure out where to store things. But for a language that's very close to the implementation, like C, making the object lifetime explicit is sort of a natural design choice that gives the programmer control over what's going on. But you're right, in general this is just a matter of how you design the language and whether you're able to compile or run programs written in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing a compiler with the primitive power of the old times and you'd realize flexibility is something you'd rather kill to get the software to work.

Putting variables first, then other statements simply made their parser/compiler code simpler.